# How to recover lost NTFS partition on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery

I have a problem with partition. I had one with name `E:` and I don't know why it has been lost. (look at the screenshot).

I think it is a problem with partition table.

Can I recover my partition with files inside?

This problem is showed on the picture:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a free and open source software you can use for that purpose. It is a command-line software, but very easy to use. You will simply have to choose the hard disk that contains the broken partition (most likely `/dev/sda`), choose the partition table type (either Intel or EFI GPT), choose Analyze, and follow the succeeding prompts.